# Cannot install openjdk-8-jre on 16.04 LTS at Myanmar

Tags: apt, package-management, java, openjdk, jre

When I type `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre` , it shows as below and didn't install.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre-headless : Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless but it is not going to be installed
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-8-jre : Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-dbg:i386 : Depends: vlc-nox:i386 (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct unmet dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

For more info: [How to Install Java](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)